# How can I rewire my bathroom fan, light, and receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, exhaust-fan

My bathroom has one switch that powers the fan and light.  In that electrical box, there is also a hard wired electrical outlet that sits in the bathroom.  Since I don't have room for a 2 gang box in my location, I would like to install a double rocker in that one gang box.  Can I get a diagram showing what that wiring would look like?

Top switch: Light on
Bottom switch: Fan on
Always on: electrical outlet

This is the switch:

[image: Dual Switch]

EDIT:

So I took a look at my current plug and this is what I've discovered.  The switch has no ground, only a white wire that leaves it from the bottom and is HOT (I checked with a Klein).   The upper black wire powers the fan and light when in the up position. I can see that lower white wire that's connected to the switch, comes back as black and is one of those 3 hot ones i've labeled.

[image]

Comment: Do you want 2 switches and a receptacle in a single gang box, or do you want 2 switches in one single gang box and a receptacle in a different single gang box?

Comment: I'd like 2 switches in one gang box, and a receptacle in a different gang box. thanks.

Comment: Also, I accidentally broke off the connector on the right side of the switch between the black screws. Knowing that, would I still be able to use this switch?

Comment: Are there two sets of wires to the fixture?  One would be for the fan and the other for the light.

Comment: Yes. Two. One would be for the fan, the other for the light. Separate.

Comment: I don't see an outlet, not even room for one in that box.  Is there one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

If you accidentally broke the tab between the black (common) screws on the swtich, simply use two short pigtails off the supply line like this...

[image]

If you have two separate cables (one to the fan, and one to the light), then you'd wire it up like this...

[image]

And again if you've clipped the tab between the terminals, it will look like this...

[image]

---

Here is what the original circuit would have looked like with 3 wire cable...

[image]

And here is what the original circuit would have looked like with two separate cables...

[image]

---

Don't forget, since it's a bathroom the receptacle has to be protected by a ground-fault circuit interrupter (GFCI).

Comment: Your last picture looks right except one thing.  The middle picture of the switch - my lower cable it white, and is hot. Is that possible?  The upper black cable is spot on - oh and there's no ground in my outlet (I plan on fixing that!).

Comment: My buddy told me this is a possible switch leg - which I have  NO idea about.

Comment: @OnlyHumain It sounds like the power comes to the switch from the fixture, while all my diagrams have power going from the receptacle.  It would be easier if you told us how many wires and cables are at each location, and the color of the insulation of each wire.  Otherwise we are playing a guessing game.

Comment: Sorry for that. I too was under the impression that the power was coming from the receptacle.  I've removed my drawing and uploaded a picture of the outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Please excuse my artwork.  I need more practice.  The yellowish wires are the white neutral wires (I should have made the background gray.) and are all tied together and also connect to the neutral of the outlet.

The bare copper grounds are all tied together and connected to the ground screw of both items. A wire nut capped pigtail is fine for that, though be careful to keep the bare wire away from the neutral and hot terminals.
[image]

As requested, this is how it likely looks with a simple switch controlling both light and fan:
[image]

Comment: If that is right I don't know how mine are working!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular switch, but usually black terminals are "common".   however, as long as you've broken any tabs between the terminals, your diagram works just fine.

Comment: @Tester101:  I considered turning the switch photo over to match, but decided against it with respect to the OP's tab being removed.

Comment: Awesome drawings! Thanks.  What would this look like in it's current setup? With one switch?

Comment: Keep in mind, while your diagram will work. It's an atypical installation, and could confuse any future electricians.

Comment: @Tester101:  I hope to avoid any electrician who would be confused by so minor a faux pas.

Comment: @user14946:  Are you asking for another diagram where one switch controls fan plus light simultaneously?

Comment: Yes - I'd like to see the current setup Vs the new one. A before and an after. So I don't get confused.

Comment: @user14946:  I have updated the answer with a best guess at what it should look like "before".

Comment: @wallyk I hope to avoid DIYers that hook up devices backwards.

Comment: My setup looks more like wallyk's diagram.  Once I get home I'll post my successes.

Comment: I've added more detail to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Top Left - black wire going to that light.

Bottom Left - black wire going to that light.

Bottom right - power in - black

Tie your neutrals together in one cap.

Tie your grounds together in another cap.  - given plastic box

I have to say I just installed a fancier version of the same thing in 3 bathrooms in my house and the [Lutron Light Dimmer and Fan Timer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017O2VIW) are awesome.  I actually put a nightlight (in my bathroom fans) on the fan timer so you don't have to do much late at night.

Comment: I love that dimmer! I may go to HD and replace the one I have with that one. Thanks for the advice.